# Determining whether the following is homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to solve a question, I almost have the solution and have some few points to ask. Here is the question:

Let $\Bbb Z$ be the additive group of integers and let $\Bbb R^*$ be the multiplicative group of the real numbers. Show that $\varphi\colon \Bbb Z \to \Bbb R$ given by $\varphi(m) = 2^m$ is a homomorphism. What is the range of $\varphi$?

I show the homomorphism like the following:
$$
\varphi(x+y)=2^{x+y}=2^x2^y=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)
$$
for $x\in\Bbb Z$ and $y\in\Bbb R^*$.

First of all, is my way of showing homomorphism is true? And secondly, what does it mean "the range of $\varphi$", what is it, and how can I find it?

Thank you

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method of showing that $\phi$ is a homomorphism is fine.

The range of $\phi$ is the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ under $\phi$. That is to say, the set of all $x \in\mathbb{R}^*$ such that $x = \phi(n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, or $\{\phi(n) : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: thanks, and can we say that the range is (0, infinity) ?

Comment: @bigO, no, it is just the set $\{ 2^n : n \in \Bbb{Z} \}$.

Comment: @bigO That depends, can you find some integer $n$ such that $\phi(n) = 0$?

Comment: no, but since the limit goes to 0 as n goes to minus inf., i thought (0,inf) is fine. Am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid. the range is only the set of points in the target set that can be mapped to by the given function, so for example, $0$ is not in the set (although there is a sequence of points in the set that tend to $0$. Andreas has given the precise formulation of what the set is above. Do you see why, for example, $3$ is not in the range?